# Creating a loop for timer in outsystem?

Tags: loops, foreach, timer, outsystems

I am new to outsystems. I have a timer that cache 10 contacts each time. how do I make a loop so that it goes through all the contacts ?

I am confused where to create the for each loop? timer indicates a 0365 file

or is there any other way to load the contact page faster?

Answer (score 0):

Create a server action where you are going to process your contacts, consume the server action from your timer. Your contact should be a list, from there you can loop it.